# Как правильно задать пространство имен

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как на примере этого класса исправить ошибку компиляции?

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    T b;
    struct C
    {
        T d;
    };
    C* func(T f);
public:
    void func2(T f);
};

template <class T>
A<T>::C* A<T>::func(T f)//ошибка
{
    C* c = new C;
    c->d = f;
    return c;
}

template<class T>
void A<T>::func2(T f)
{
    C* some = func(f);
    b = f;
}
```

Ошибка (clang 10):

> error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'A::C'

Comment: было бы неплохо текст ошибки вставить в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указать, что это тип - добавив `typename`:

```
typename A<T>::C* A<T>::func(T f)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Павел, если данный ответ решил Вашу проблему - отметьте его принятым.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать *trailing return type*:

Объявление:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    /* code */
    auto func(T f) -> C*;
};
```

Определение:

```
template<typename T>
auto A<T>::func(T f) -> C*
{
    /* code */
}
```

Ознакомиться с деталями можно на следующих ресурсах:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function
2. http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl